# How can I find the values of $x$ where the tangent line is horizontal?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How can I find the values of $x$ where the tangent line is horizontal?

I have done the first part of the problem. And to find the value of $x$, I think I'm just supposed to set the derivative equal to zero. But it's not correct. I have done the problem several times and I'm getting $-3$, but that's wrong.

> Suppose that $$f(x)=(2x+-2)^{1/5}.$$
>
> (A) Find an equation for the tangent line to the graph of $f(x)$ at $x=2$.

Tangent line: $$y=\frac{x\cdot2^{\frac15}}5+\frac35\cdot2^{\frac15}\qquad\hbox{correct}$$

> (B) Find all values of $x$ where the tangent line is horizontal, and enter them as a comma separated list (e.g., $2,-3,6$). If there are none, enter *none*.

Average of $x$ values: $$-3\qquad\hbox{incorrect}$$

Answer (score 1):

A horizontal tangent line means it's slope is $0$ so what you want here is to find (average of) all $x$ such that
$\dfrac{\textrm dy}{\textrm dx}=0$. In this case, you get
$$\dfrac25(2x-2)^{-4/5}=0$$
which has no solutions. So the correct answer should be `none`.

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

You solved the equation *tangent line*=0, but that is the tangent line at x=2.

You should have solved *derivative*=0.